# Probability question dealing with standard normal variables and De Moivre Laplace theorem

Tags: probability, expected-value

To examine the accuracy of an algorithm that selects random numbers from the set $\{1, 2, …, 40\},$ $100,000$ numbers are selected and there are $3500$ ones. Given that the expected number of ones is $2500,$ is it fair to say that this algorithm is not accurate?

[The picture here is the steps I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgM6Z.jpg)

I uploaded this question on chegg, but I am still very confused with how the last three lines are determined. How do we know that $Z$ can be between $-3.8$ and $3.8.$ Any hints would be incredibly appreciated!!

Comment: Please  type the question and read [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20formatting) for good formatting. Btw, the picture doesn´t show the whole question. A reply to answers is welcomed.

Comment: Just updated the question!

Comment: What you wrote on istack looks good except for the part that says $-3.8\le Z\le 3.8.$ I have no idea how that is supposed to bear upon the problem.

Comment: @emitsch I agree to the comment of Michael Hardy.

Comment: @michael-hardy That is what I am confused about; I asked this question on chegg but have not understood how that part came into the problem. The final answer matches what the book has, but I have no idea how they got that the standard normal variable Z is defined to be between -3.8 and 3.8.

Comment: ok, I'll hazard a guess. Someone said they would always reject any null hypothesis for which $|Z|>3.8,$ and then someone copied something that that person wrote while neglecting to include a comment that was made orally. It's not unusual for students to do things like that if they don't understand what was said orally and not written.

Comment: I think I figured it out; we use the standard normal distribution table in class, and those values go exactly from -3.8 to 3.8, but doesn't account for z values outside that spectrum. I think because the z value is supposed to be greater than or equal to 20.25, the table doesn't have a probability value

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of `1`'s in $n=100,000$ draws with probability $p=1/40$ of `1` at each draw be $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n,p).$ In R, $P(X \ge 3000) = 1 - P(X \le 2999) \approx 0.$

```
1 - pbinom(2999, 100000, 1/40)
[1] 0
```

As mentioned in the question, $\mu_X=E(X) = np = 2500.$ Also, $\sigma_X = SD(X) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 49.3710.$

```
sqrt(100000*(1/40)*(39/40))
[1] 49.37104
```

Thus $3000$ is $\frac{3000-2500}{49.27} = 8.7152$ standard deviations above the mean. Binomial distributions with such large $n$ are approximately normal, and the Empirical Rule
states that there is almost no probability of having an
observation more than 3 standard deviations above the mean.

```
(3000 - 2500)/57.3710
[1] 8.715205
```

A normal approximation to $P(X \ge 3000) = P(X \ge 2999.5)\approx 0$
can be obtained directly in R by using a normal PDF:

```
1 - pnorm(2999.5, 2500, 57.3719)
[1] 0
```

Ordinarily, you could also come close to a normal approximation by standardizing and using printed normal tables, as follows:

$$P(X \ge 3000) = P(X > 2999.5)\\
= P\left(\frac{X-\mu_x}{\sigma_x} > 
\frac{2999.5-2500}{57.3790}\right)\\
\approx P(Z > 8.7043) \approx 0.$$
where the final result is far beyond tabled values,
and so must be taken as $0.$

```
(2999.5-2500)/57.3790
[1] 8.705275
```

Your posted handwritten work seems mainly in the
right direction, except that I can't read the
last few lines.